# Food tracker app from apple site

Tags: ios, swift

> Error : Cannot subscript a value of type '[String: AnyOject]?' with an
>   index of type 'String'

I've been trying to follow the tutorial from [this developers site](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1):  but I can't seem to make this code work.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    let selectedImage = editingInfo[SUIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    // Set photoImageView to selected image
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage
```

Comment: Hey @Ooshiny can you elaborate a little more on your code/problem? Is this the only error you are getting? You have only provided one method, but it seems you are referencing variables outside of it. Can you provide the code where you define  `SUIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`

Comment: I went through the tutorial you linked, and the code you posted is not included, so you probably have changed/modified some things. Please post more code so we can help debug.

Answer (score 1):

That method change in swift 1.2 Apple didn't modify their documentation

you change the function into this one:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

}
```

And it should work

Answer (score 0):

editingInfo is an Optional as denoted by the trailing '?'. You should bind it by doing an if let:

```
if let dict = editingInfo {
    let selectedImage = dict[SUIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage
}
else {
     // Handle the case where editingInfo is nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response, the code seems to work though. I used a bit of both answers, it seems the formatting on the tutorial has changed since it came out.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, info: [String : AnyObject]!) {

    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

     //Set photoImageView to selected image
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```